# Replace image in a href with image from another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to swap the image in the a element with the image in the img element.

I have done this in a similar situation with the script below:

```
$('a.testColorbox.cboxElement img').each(function () {
var src = $(this).attr('src');
$(this).attr('src', src.replace("/70/70", "/640/480"));   
});
```

However, since the file ending is ~640~480~1 for this given element this doesn´t work. How to a target this element? I have several elements with this where the same variable is the file ending so i need to target that

```
70~70~1
640~480~1
```

HTML:

```
<li> 
  <a rel="colorboxRel-1637597101" href="/img/0~F76E4571-33C1-4CA6-A88C-0D8AFC3DCC6A~640~480~1" class="testColorbox cboxElement" onclick="return false;">    
  <img style="border-style:solid 1px;" src="/img/0~F76E4571-33C1-4CA6-A88C-0D8AFC3DCC6A~70~70~1" alt="Framsidan" title="Framsidan">  
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the original ending of the `img` will always be `~70~70~1.jpg` then you can simplify your `replace()` call, like this:

```
$('a.testColorbox.cboxElement img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', function(i, src) {
        return src.replace("~70~70~", "~640~480~");
    });   
});
```

Comment: Hmm. that was way to easy. Not sure what I was thinking... Thanks, works great.

Comment: No problem, glad to help